# How to take selected data from VB.net drop down list

Tags: vb.net

I am currently practicing VB.net in Visual Studio 2013 and i have been asked to create a drop down list with data from a table which i have down and is working. What i am stuck on is how to pull the selected option from the drop down list and use that to display in a Label Web Control to show on the screen when a button is pressed to confirm the selection, Can anyone Help?

My Code on the Default.aspx.vb file

```
Dim dsData1 As New DataSet
    dsData1 = tableData()


    DDList.DataSource = dsData1
    DDList.DataValueField = "code"
    DDList.DataTextField = "description"
    DDList.DataBind()
    DDList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
    DDList.SelectedIndex = 0
```

My code in my function.vb file;

```
Public Shared Function tableData() As DataSet

    Dim oraConnect As New OracleConnection
    oraConnect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("smart_dev").ConnectionString

    Dim oraCommand As New OracleCommand

    oraCommand.Connection = oraConnect
    oraCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text

    Dim lsSQL As String = ""
    lsSQL = "SELECT code, description FROM ref_code WHERE domain = 'SPECIALTY'"

    oraCommand.CommandText = lsSQL

    Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(oraCommand)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)

    Return ds
End Function
```

So basiaclly i need help with which one of these pieces of code do i edit and with what code if i open the page in a browser select an option from the dropdown and it displays on the screen.

Thank you

If i have confused anyone i apologise:)

Comment: you want to show selected item in drop down to some another control(a label) ??

Comment: a guess :  on your `button`'s click event `If DDList.Text <> vbNullString Then
            yourLable.text = DDList.Text
        End If`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i did try your code but it doesnt like the .Text part after If DDList. Im not sure if its possible to save a selection from the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text
```

If it's a web form the .SelectedItem.Text will only be available after the view state has been loaded, If you need to get around that you can do the following:

```
dim selectedText as String = page.request(DDList.UniqueId)
```

Comment: I tried this...      Dim radioOne As String = DDList.Text
        Dim radioTwo As String = DDList2.Text
        Dim selectedText As String = Page.Request(DropDownList.)

        If DDList.SelectedItem.Text = True Then
            Output.Text &= radionOne
        End If                                                    But i am missing the DropDownList."" as it only gives me one option which is 'DisabledCssClass'

Comment: Is it a web form you are programming?

Comment: Please see the edit, you need to use the uniqueid of the instance of your dropdownlist... eg ddl1.UniqueId

Comment: yes i have added a dropdownlist from the ToolBox in visual studio. i apologise im not sure what the uniqueId is apart from DDList? but this doesnt work,, i worked out what you meant sorry, but its telling me know that it does not like the first line of my if statement 'If DDlist.SelectedItem.Text = True Then

Comment: If DDlist.SelectedItem.Text = "True" , [True] on it's own will be evaluated as a boolean value, ["True"] will be evaluated as a string..not sure what you're trying to do with testing true to be honest..

Comment: Ok lovely it seems happy with the code now but when i select my option on the web page and press enter nothing is printed :(

Comment: i was trying to use True as to say if an option on the ddlist was selected 'true' then display this selection. I wasn't sure if this was the correct way to do it?